# Mongo db read performance improvement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb we are storing flat data (our Event Object) containing below fields :

1. EventReceivedTimeStamp
2. EventStatus (SENT, FAILED, REJECTED)
3. UniqueId
4. System (5 systems)
5. Trigger (20 triggers)
6. ErrorMessage

Data Size & Updates

- Data Count: 270 million entries
- Updates per day: 3 million (3 million new added and 3 million old removed per day)
- Document size: approx 2-3 kb

Search criteria:

1. EventReceivedTime Range and Status
2. EventReceived Range and System and trigger and status
3. Unique Id

We created compound indexes/index on the above fields.

We are not getting response times in milliseconds while performing search on the data set. How can we improve the performance of mongodb in our case?

**SampleDocument**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570cd8a55b66f3af1b4bd17e"),
    "_class" : "com.companyName.commons.dto.EventRecord",
    "uuid" : BinData(3,"10OXD+C51CEXS4E8jz0vnQ=="),
    "moc" : "APP_NOTIFICATION",
    "eventReceivedDateTime" : ISODate("2016-04-12T11:14:43.766Z"),
    "retryAttemptsMade" : 0,
    "retryAttemptDateTime" : ISODate("2016-04-12T11:14:43.766Z"),
    "eventStatus" : "FAILED",
    "systemName" : "OMS",
    "triggerName" : "COD_ORDER_NIGHT",
    "referenceId" : "39437515",
    "aggregatorBased" : true,
    "sentToDndQueue" : false,
    "lastProcessedDateTime" : ISODate("2016-04-12T11:14:44.294Z"),
    "errorMessage" : "Exception in validating attributes ",
    "suborderCodes" : [
        "39437515"
    ],
    "dndEvent" : false
}

**db.collection_name.getIndices()**

    [
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "uuid" : 1
            },
            "name" : "uuid",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "moc" : 1
            },
            "name" : "moc",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "eventReceivedDateTime" : 1
            },
            "name" : "eventReceivedDateTime",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "retryAttemptsMade" : 1
            },
            "name" : "retryAttemptsMade",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "retryAttemptDateTime" : 1
            },
            "name" : "retryAttemptDateTime",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "eventStatus" : 1
            },
            "name" : "eventStatus",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "systemName" : 1
            },
            "name" : "systemName",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "triggerName" : 1
            },
            "name" : "triggerName",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "referenceId" : 1
            },
            "name" : "referenceId",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "aggregatorBased" : 1
            },
            "name" : "aggregatorBased",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "salesforceTagged" : 1
            },
            "name" : "salesforceTagged",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "sentToDndQueue" : 1
            },
            "name" : "sentToDndQueue",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "senderId" : 1
            },
            "name" : "senderId",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "lastProcessedDateTime" : 1
            },
            "name" : "lastProcessedDateTime",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "errorMessage" : 1
            },
            "name" : "errorMessage",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "suborderCodes" : 1
            },
            "name" : "suborderCodes",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "dndEvent" : 1
            },
            "name" : "dndEvent",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "eventStatus" : 1,
                "eventReceivedDateTime" : 1
            },
            "name" : "SDR",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        },
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                "triggerName" : 1,
                "eventStatus" : 1,
                "systemName" : 1,
                "eventReceivedDateTime" : 1
            },
            "name" : "STSDR",
            "ns" : "admin.event_record"
        }
    ]
```

**Note** : will share the explain output

Comment: Are you using indexes? Can you provide us with example data flows?

Comment: We need hard data here: sample document, query, output of `yourQuery.explain()`, output of `db.yourcoll.getIndices()`

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg : I have shared the sample document along with the indices. I will share the explain output in some time as our data is on cloud and i am not able to access it as of now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1). You can use Bulk operations to read, write and updates. It reduces the time drastically.

2). Create the schemas so that fields which used together are in one collection.

3). You have to make the search fast since even when write data need to search existing data. So make indexes bravely. If you create more indexes, data write operations goes slower.(Additionally need to update indexes)

4). use the uniqeId as the _id

Comment: please, consider to upvote the answer if you got help. It will helpful other with the same kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

We improved performace of our queries by :

1) Changed the pagination logic. Instead of using pageNumber/PageSize , we started using id of the last element send in the last response.

2) secondly we started giving hints to our queries so that it should use proper compound indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you have created the compound indexes. While creating compound indexes, make sure to check how the query would be run on the collection. Define compound index such that the the first keys of index are match (in query - the equal statement), then add keys which are range based in the query. Refer https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity.

Also, make sure that you have sufficient memory(RAM) to process the datasets. You can refer the official MongoDB docs - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram.